# Min heap does not work as intended in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am having problem with the min heap algorithm.

The code I programmed returned an array that incorrectly arranged, below is my code, can someone help me to find where should I change?

Thank you.

The data was under `ELEMENT arr[]`, where `ELEMENT` is a *struct*:

```
struct ELEMENT{
    int key;
};

void constructMinHeap(ELEMENT arr[], int size, int num){
    int left = leftNode(num);
    int right = rightNode(num);
    int min;

    if (left < size && arr[left].key < arr[num].key){
        min = left;
    } else{
        min = num;
    }

    if (right < size && arr[right].key < arr[min].key){
        min = right;
    }

    if(min != num){
        swap(&arr[num].key, &arr[min].key);
        constructMinHeap(arr, size, num);
    }
}

ELEMENT* buildHelper (ELEMENT arr[], int size){
    int i = size / 2 - 1;
    while (i >= 0){
        constructMinHeap(arr, size, i);
        i--;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

And here is the code for calculating leftNode and rightNode:

```
int leftNode(int num){
    return 2 * num + 1;
}

int rightNode(int num){
    return (2 * num) + 2;
}
```

The following code is for storing data into the `ELEMENT arr[]`:

```
ifstream infile("somefilename.txt");
    if (infile.good()) {
        int i = 0;
        int size;

        infile >> size;
        ELEMENT arr[size];
        while (i < size){
            infile >> arr[i].key;
            i++;
        }

        BuildHeap(h, arr, size);
        infile.close();

    } else{
        cout << "File \"somefilename.txt\" does not exist in the current directory.";
    }
```

When the file's content is

> 4 4 3 2 1

The feedback becomes:

> 1 4 2 3

Comment: Hey and welcome to Stack Overflow. For your best experience here please provide complete code samples that demonstrate the problem you are having (and only that problem). Use [mcve] as inspiration. The true beauty of working with a [mcve] is creating one almost always reveals the bug to you and eliminates the need for the question. Everybody wins.

Comment: @rustyx Isn't the feedback should be 1 3 2 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive call for `num` is incorrect, it has no progress since it calls the same `num` again. In case if the node is swapped with its smallest child, that child should be further pushed down until it takes its proper place. This will guarantee that the binary subtree rooted at `num` is heapified

The correct recursion is the following (you didn't show the swap so I added my own one):

```
void swap(ELEMENT* e1, ELEMENT* e2)
{
         int tmp = e1->key;
         e1->key = e2->key;
         e2->key = tmp;
}
void constructMinHeap(ELEMENT arr[], int size, int num){

    int left = leftNode(num);
    int right = rightNode(num);
    int min = num;

    if (left < size && arr[left].key   < arr[min].key){
        min = left;
    }

    if (right < size && arr[right].key < arr[min].key){
        min = right;
    }

    if(min != num)
    {
        swap(&arr[num], &arr[min]);
        constructMinHeap(arr, size, min);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again. But when I tried to run a larger test file, it gives me a bad result again. The data I tried was `12 9 10 11 12 2 4 6 5 3 1 7 8`.

Comment: Please ignore my previous message. I figured it out myself.

Comment: @しらゆき my bad, I made a bug. Heapification of each node should be performed in top-to-bottom way. Check the updated version

Comment: @しらゆき also, first version of `buildHelper` was actually fine - heapification can start from index=`size/2-1` because all indexes from `size/2` to `size-1` are leaf nodes so they don't need to be heapified